# why $\lim_{n \to\infty}((\log n)^n)/(n^{0.5\log n})=\infty ?$

Tags: limits

How can I show that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\log n)^n}{n^{0.5\log n}}=\infty ?
$$

I tried to turn it to :
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n\log(\log n)}}{2^{0.5 \log^2 n}}=\infty ?
$$
how can i procceed?

Comment: Of course, this depends on what you filled the sandwich with…

Comment: Try getting both numerator and denominator written to the same base. Probably base $n$ is simplest to work with, so solve for $u$ in ${(\log n)}^n = n^u,$ which you can do by first taking $\log$ of both sides (to de-exponentialize things down to basic multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\color{blue}{n\log\log n}-\color{red}{\frac12\ln^2n})=\infty$, which follows from the blue (red) term growing faster (slower) than $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state the base of your logarithms.  By default, "$\log$" is the common logarithm, to base 10, although various disciplines have different defaults.  So I carefully preserve your ambiguous notation.

$$  \frac{(\log n)^n}{n^{0.5\log n}} = \frac{(\mathrm{e}^{\ln \log n})^{n}}{(\mathrm{e}^{\ln n})^{0.5 \log n}} = \mathrm{e}^{(n \ln \log n) - (0.5 \ln n \log n)}  \text{.}  $$
Since exponentiation is continuous, you now study
$$  \mathrm{e}^{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ((n \ln \log n) - (0.5 \ln n \log n))}  $$
Notice that the single factor of fastest growth is $n$, so the limit is 
$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\left(\ln \log n - \frac{0.5 \ln n \log n}{n} \right)  $$
and it should be evident that this has the form $\infty(\infty - 0)$, so diverges to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\left( {\log n} \right)^n  = e^{n\log \log n} 
$$
and
$$
n^{\frac{{\log n}}
{2}}  = e^{^{\frac{{\left( {\log n} \right)^2 }}
{2}} } 
$$
you have that

$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{\left( {\log n} \right)^n }}
{{n^{\frac{{\log n}}
{2}} }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{e^{n\log \log n} }}
{{e^{^{\frac{{\left( {\log n} \right)^2 }}
{2}} } }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } e^{n\log \log n - \frac{{\left( {\log n} \right)^2 }}
{2}}  =  + \infty 
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the expression as
$$\frac{\mathrm e^{n \log\log n}}{\mathrm e^{\frac12\log^2 n}}=
\mathrm e^{n \log\log n-\frac12\log^2 n}$$
and show the exponent 
$$n \log\log n-\tfrac12\log^2 n=n\log\log n\biggl(1-\frac{\log^2 n}{2n\log\log n}\biggr)$$
tends to $\infty$.